# To prove a statement related to mean value property

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that 
\begin{align}
\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{{a + b \cos \theta}} d\theta
 \end{align}

$a\gt|b|$ & $a,b \in R$
(The mean-value property for holomorphic functions states that if $f$ is holomorphic in an open disc centered at $z_{0}$ of radius $R$, then
$$f(z_{0}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(z_{0} + re^{i\theta})\, d\theta$$
for any $0 < r < R$. )
If I need to use above property to prove then I should take $f(z)= \frac{1}{a + b cos z}$ if I am not wrong then compare real and imaginary parts. How to proceed further? Thanks in advance

Comment: You equation appears to state that if we integrate the inverse of the radius through the rotation of a circle we arrive at $2\pi$ times the inverse of the diameter, which should be self-evident.

Comment: I am afraid to say you that's too complicated to understand.

Comment: Actually I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim as stated is false. Consider $a= 1$ and $b=1$
then you have
\begin{align}
\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{d\theta}{1+\cos\theta}
\end{align}
which does not converge.

Comment: I am really sorry I forgot to add conditions on a & b that $a\gt|b|$ & $a,b \in R$